# How do I autorun a vm on VMware Workstation at startup?

Tags: virtualization, vmware, 23.04, vmware-workstation

I'm using Ubuntu 23.04 and VMware Workstation Pro 17.

I created a shell script called, vmware.sh, with the following instructions in it and saved it in /etc/init.d/ so that it would execute at startup:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Start vm at startup

vmware -X pathToMyVM.vmx
```

If I type this command, `vmware -X pathToMyVM.vmx`, in the Terminal manually, my VM starts in fullscreen mode, as intended; however, I can't get this script to execute at startup. How do I resolve this issue?